# simple MDX query causes 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: performance, mdx

I am new to MDX and am pulling my hairs out over this 'System.OutOfMemoryException'. Please take a look at the following simple query. It may be something obvious that I missed.

The customerID and the Service Date have one-to-one relationship in 2 separate dimensions. Each dimension have roughly 3 million rows. The query is to retrieve the total charges for each customer with service date in 2013.

Any pointer to improving this query is very much appreciated. Thank you!

```
SELECT non empty{[Measures].[Sum Charges]} on 0
     , non empty([Customer].[CustomerID].children
            ,[Date - Service Date].[Service Date].children
        )on 1
    FROM [Cube]
    WHERE [Date - Service Date].[Service Date Year].&[2013]
```

Comment: Have you tried taking `,[Date - Service Date].[Service Date].children` out of the script - does it run then? Similarly for `[Customer].[CustomerID].children` does leaving that out avoid the error ?

Comment: Use NonEmpty  then non empty.